# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' adding more column

Tags: python, pandas

i try to adding new column on my dataset, but this map function get me error. How to fix this?

```
    train_df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv")
train_df['subject'] = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv",header= None,squeeze=True)
train_df["label"] = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv", header = None, squeeze = True)
label = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv", header = None, squeeze = True)
label_name = label.map({1: "WALKING", 2:"WALKING_UPSTAIRS", 3:"WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS", 4:"SITTING", 5:"STANDING", 6:"LYING"})
```

And this is the error notification

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-fb7708d65296> in <module>()
      3 train_df["label"] = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv", header = None, squeeze = True)
      4 label = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/HumanActivity/data/train.csv", header = None, squeeze = True)
----> 5 label_name = label.map({1: "WALKING", 2:"WALKING_UPSTAIRS", 3:"WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS", 4:"SITTING", 5:"STANDING", 6:"LYING"})

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: `map` is a `Series` function you are applying it on a `Datafrrame`. Check this, how to use map: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: i want to add one more column after column label

Answer (score 1):

The `map` function in `pandas series` not in `pandas DataFrame`, if you have `pandas series` and you need to replace some values you will change them by passing dictionary in it. and if you need to change values in dataframe regardless of which column they belong to, you can use `pd.DataFrame.replace(value, replacement)`

Comment: thank you. but anyway, i don't want to replace the value i want to add one more column based on previous column

Comment: please share sample data and the desired output